# Is it possible to access the same sqlite database with php and javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, database, sqlite

Php is able to find the database i created with javascript,
but php is unable to find the table and (therefore the data) i made with javascript.

Opening db in php

```
$dbhandle = sqlite_open('db.sqlite', 0666, $error);
```

Opening db in javascript

```
db = openDatabase('db.sqlite', '1.0', 'db.sqlite', 65536);
```

I hope i provided enough information, if more code is required please let me know.

Comment: You're not familiar with how PHP and JS work, right?

Comment: No one can help you without context.

Comment: I totally forgot about server/client side... Does anybody know how i Can download the sqlite db and access it that way with php?

Comment: Having a client-side database seems an odd way to develop a we bapp, I would leave it server-side and look into AJAX to pass data between PHP and JS.

Comment: I have to save stuff client-side this way the web-app can be used offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is client side, while PHP is server side.

You will need to keep seperate databases and sync them